# Scheduled crawls delayed

Tags: 2013, search

I just confirmed on one of my 2013 environments that the incremental/full scheduled crawls keep getting delayed inexplicably since I canceled one of them earlier this week that had run for too long. The last completed crawl was several days ago and since then it has said crawls were planned for the same night, but those crawls never kick off and the next day it says the crawls are scheduled for that night instead. This has happened three times in a row with no crawls being executed at all. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

**Edit:** Examining the ULS logs shows a rapid string of SQL connection errors. Checking the SQL server itself revealed no errors on that side, so I just rebooted the SP server and everything magically went away. But now... the Timer Service is eating up 75% of the CPU power. I guess that's a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the Crawl Logs, if there is any thing which give you direction.

- Check the ULS logs for the around the schudle time frame.
- Any Antivirus running.
- Check any other job / process running which having the conflict to crawl.
- try to change the crawl schedule to different time.

Comment: The ULS logs aren't showing anything suspicious that I can see. No AV software is interfering. No other jobs or processes are interfering *as far as I can see* (though I'm not sure what all to look for). I'll try rescheduling next... Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: enable the verbose level for search and monitor it. also check the timer job history during the time frame.